# Jest: How to test event listener on 3rd party window object?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have an object called `web3` that I listen to events on and use to set cookies:

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie'
import _ from 'lodash'

const cookies = new Cookies()

const setUserId = () => {
  if (_.isUndefined(window.web3)) return

  window.web3.currentProvider.publicConfigStore.on(
    'update',
    ({ selectedAddress }) => {
      cookies.set('userId', selectedAddress)
    }
  )
}

export default {
  setUserId,
}
```

I'm trying to test this in jest but I'm stuck with how I would:

1) Mock `Cookies`

2) Mock `web3.currentProvider.publicConfigStore.on('update', ...)`

Could someone help?

Answer (score 1):

To mock `Cookies` you need to mock the imported module so that it returns a function that returns an object with the `set` method which is a mock. You can use just a function cause in JavaScript in this case there is no real difference between a class and a function.

```
jest.mock('universal-cookie', ()=> jest.fn())
import Cookie from 'universal-cookie'

const setCookie = jest.fn()
Cookie.mockImplementation(()=> ({set: setCookie}))
```

If you don't need to check on the `set` function you could also do the mocking in one line:

```
jest.mock('universal-cookie', ()=> ()=> ({set: jest.fn()})
```

To access anything in the global namespace like `window` you can use the `global` keyword in jest to access it. On this you can just add whatever you want;

```
const on = jest.fn()
global.web3 = { 
  currentProvider: {
    publicConfigStore: {
      on
    }
  }
}
```

The last step would be to call the callback that is passed to `on` using [`mock.calls`](http://dev-048.local:65274/Dash/oyomfxbz/jest/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockcalls)

```
on.mock.calls[0][1]({selectedAddress: 'someAddress'})
```